# Can anyone help me parse this definition?

Tags: functional-analysis, definition

[image: Definition of "Ground State" from Adimurthi-Tintarev 2010]

I am pretty new to and bad at research in the area of functional inequalities and came across this very opaque definition in the paper of Adimurthi-Tintarev (2010). I understand most of the terminology and ideas here, but what is meant in this definition by the weak-* limit of the sequence $\{x_k\}$? I know that the weak* topology is the coarsest topology on $X^*$ making all maps $J_x:X^*\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous, where $J_x(f)=f(x)$ for all $f\in X^*$. I also know that if we define $J:X\rightarrow X^{**}$ by $x\mapsto J_x$ then we obtain the "canonical injection". I am very much regretting not paying more attention in my functional analysis class right now.

Comment: Please do not rely on images for key information about your quey. [See here for reasons why](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).